# sub-domain best practice with google universal analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I have a main domain(www.abc.com) and 2 sub-domains (def.abc.com) I'm trying to figure out whats the best way to track this in universal analytics. one option is same property id on everything and filter in profile view. I think the downside is that someone going to www.abc.com and then going to def.abc.com will look like direct on def.abc.com.

I could also use a new property for each one. But I don't know if it will just create self referrals and create new sessions when someone is going back and forth between www.abc.com and def.abc.com.

So what is the general best practice for this scenario?

Comment: You are describing two different paths which both require two different answers depending on what You want to happen with the data in your accounts. 

Do you want sessionalization to be maintained between your subdomains, or do you want them as separate sites in your GA account?

Answer (score 0):

### Multiple trackers

if you have enabled parameter for subdomain tracking ('auto' value):

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
```

Then all subdomains have the same client Id across multiple trackers.

Now you can add more trackers to duplicate tracking into two separate properties.

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Z', 'auto', {'name': 'subdomainTracker'});
```

So your initial configuration on subdomain will looks like:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Z', 'auto', {'name': 'subdomainTracker'});
```

And sending pageview will looks like:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Z', 'auto', {'name': 'subdomainTracker'});  

ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('subdomainTracker.send', 'pageview');
```

### Documentation

Try to read more about multiple trackers on: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced